# Infragistics UltraGrid CellChange Event

Tags: drop-down-menu, cell, onchange, infragistics, ultrawingrid

guys!

I have ultragrid in my project, one of columns has a valueList (**dropDown**) with three string items ("Statistic", "Full Scale", "Manual", by default in runtime is "Statistic"). If I change the value in runtime (let's say I change on "Manual"), CellChange event fires, but if I want to see the value of **eventArgs.Cell** object, I will see "Statistic". And it's always one value in eventArgs.Cell. So my question is how can I change this situation? Should I handle some other events or I can change only some ultragrid's properties in design mode

Comment: cannot reproduce the behavior you describe, I CellChange event I see the new value of the cell (the value just selected) as expected and documented by Infragistics [here](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.1/CLR2.0/HTML/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid~CellChange_EV.html). Perhaps, a small code example with the behavior mentioned could be of help

Comment: In addition to code, can you clarify what you are asking?  Is it that you want to know what value the cell is changing to in the CellChange event or another event that fires when the value is changed.  Also please clarify how you are changing the value at runtime, are you doing this in code or as a user through interaction with the control?  What is meant by "I can change only some ultragrid's properties in design mode"?